# Trying to change format for named files

Tags: powershell, file-rename

I have a folder containing .VCF files that was pulled from our exchange server. Currently, they are named how the mailboxes are set up: `Lastname, Firstname MI`. I need to rename them so that they are `FirstName.LastName`.

How can I get PowerShell to read the file name, store the the characters up to the `", "` as last name and then take on what is left up to the next `" "` (if there is one) to rename the file in the format specified above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what regular expressions were invented for. Something like this should do what you want:

```psh
Get-ChildItem 'C:\temp\a\*.vcf' | % {
  $newname = $_.Name -replace '^(.*?), (.*?)(?: .*)?(\.vcf)', '$2.$1$3'
  Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $newname
}
```

Regular expression breakdown:

- `^(.*?),` matches the shortest sequence of any character (`.`) between the beginning of a string (`^`) and a comma. The parentheses group the actual match (`.*?`), so it can be referenced in the replacement string (capturing group).
- `, (.*?)` matches the shortest sequence of any character (`.`) after a comma and space, but before the next expression. Again, the match is grouped, so it can be referenced in the replacement.
- `(?: .*)?` matches a space followed by any number of characters. The trailing `?` makes this match optional (can occur zero or one times). the `(?:)` is a non-capturing group (as opposed to capturing groups from above). This is to allow grouping (sub)expressions that you don't want to reference without polluting the references list.
- `(\.vcf)` matches the file extension (a literal dot followed by the string `vcf`), again in a capturing group. Thinking about it, I should have added a trailing `$` (`(\.vcf)$`) to anchor that subexpression at the end of the string.
- The replacement string `$2.$1$3` then combines the three groups, reversing the order of first and last name by switching the order of first and second reference.

Comment: Thank you. That actually worked quite nicely! Now, I am trying to understand what, exactly, that script is doing as I've been reading up on regular expressions to try and learn this. So, below is what I think is happening and where I am not so sure...

Comment: Sorry about that...meant to return to a new line and actually posted the comment!
Would you mind explaining what is happening with regards to the regex code in the second line? I am not sure I am following the "magic" going on there.